# Detect custom shape OpenCV

Tags: opencv, real-time, shapes, detection

I want to find custom shape in OpenCV.
Shape is previously defined. I want to detect if this shape is equal or not equal to the current shape using WebCam in real time.

How can I do that? How to compare pre-defined custom shape and current shape?

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @runDOSrun..Is it possible with opencv-python?can you give me a good example or docs?

Comment: template matching and chamfer matching are common simple techniques for simple shape matching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the commenters have eluded, you can use template matching to detect custom shapes.

**So What Is Template Matching?**

[Template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching) is a technique in digital image processing for finding small parts of an image which match a template image. It can be used in manufacturing as a part of quality control, a way to navigate a mobile robot, or as a way to detect edges in images.

**Template Matching In OpenCV/Python**

> Template Matching is a method for searching and finding the location
>   of a template image in a larger image. OpenCV comes with a function
>   cv2.matchTemplate() for this purpose. It simply slides the template
>   image over the input image (as in 2D convolution) and compares the
>   template and patch of input image under the template image.

I have taken this text from [here](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html) which is a tutorial on how to perform template matching in OpenCV. You can search for any "custom shape" that you define. It includes code samples for python.

Comment: I have already read you commanded tutorial.According to all of you,I must use template matching for my application.Thanks