# How to keep content within the square contour, while delete other shape of contours?

Tags: python, image-processing, contour, opencv

My project is to scan out a paper from an image which is this[image]

After a lot of processes, the quality of images decreased. I run some code to find all the contours

```
img = cv2.imread("scan1.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) ret,bw = cv2.threshold(gray,220,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV) contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bw, cv2.RETR_CCOMP,1) cntLen = 10 ct = 0 #number of contours for cnt in contours:
    if len(cnt) > cntLen: #eliminate the noises
        ct += 1
        newimg = img.copy()
        cv2.drawContours(newimg,[cnt],0,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.imshow('Win', newimg)
        cv2.waitKey(0) print('Total contours: ',ct)
```

Obviously, there are a lot of result, but I only want to sort out all the checkbox contours and check whether people tick on it or not.

[image]

Comment: Your target check boxes have a ver specific aspect ratio (height  divided by width). Try to use that to filter the contours and see what results you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be multiple solutions, one of the ways you could go about this is:

1. Extract contours/connected components (as you are doing)
2. Do a correlation-based template matching of a square mask that you can define like shown below:
   [mask from the sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpD5L.png)
3. Followed by thresholding to get the coordinates of the peak where you applied the mask (and hence you can calculate your 4 coordinates of the box)
4. After getting the 4 coordinates of the box, you can add an additional filter based on the aspect ratio/moment of the box detected (as suggested by **eldesgraciado**)

Note:

- You’ll have to do a lot of experiments to get right value of the
  threshold and will have to have a +/- margin of the threshold
- You'll get multiple peaks of the match, in which case, you’ll have to
  take the strongest one
- when the form is filled out, you may have a situation where the pen stroke will continue outside the box, so aspect ratio has to be applied after the extraction of the coordinates of the box
- This method is very sensitive to a. Noise b. The skew of form c. the scale of the image or box changes, etc, would recommend doing some pre-processing steps like skew correction, based on your sample images.

[Template Matching Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching)

[Template Matching OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html)

[Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28428415/detect-custom-shape-opencv)

Answer (score 3):

I'm giving my answer in `C++`, but the same operations are available in `Python`.

Let's examine two possible solutions. The first one involves applying my suggested solution directly on the input image you provided. I'm filtering contours based on `aspect ratio` and `minimum width/height` thresholds.

First, read the input image and convert it to gray scale:

```
  std::string imageName = "C://opencvImages//survey.jpg";
  cv::Mat imageInput = cv::imread( imageName );

  //compute gray scale image:
  cv::cvtColor(imageInput, grayImage, cv::COLOR_RGB2GRAY );
```

Next, get the binary image via `Otsu thresholding`. Very straightforward stuff:

```
  //get binary image via Otsu:
  cv::Mat binImage;
  cv::threshold( grayImage, binImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );
  
  //Invert the image:
  binImage = 255 - binImage;
```

Now, just loop through each `contour` in the binary image and apply the corresponding *"Contour Filter"*. I’ll be looking for contours with a `minimum width/height` and `aspect ratio` between `0.9` and `1.1`. These parameters are pretty much set manually.  Let's see the code:

```
  //contour filter:
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){

    //get the bounding box for each parent countour found:
    cv::Rect bBox = cv::boundingRect( contours[i] );

    //compute aspect ratio:
    float aspectRatio = bBox.height / bBox.width;

    //set the aspect ratio thresholds:
    float lowerAspectRatio = 0.9;
    float upperAspectRatio = 1.1;

    //set the width/height thresholds:
    float minWidth = 8;
    float minHeight = 8;

    if ( (bBox.height > minHeight) && (bBox.width > minWidth) &&
         (aspectRatio >= lowerAspectRatio) && (aspectRatio <= upperAspectRatio) ) {
          cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( 0, 255, 0 );
          cv::drawContours( imageInput, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point() );
    }

  }
```

This is the output:

[image]

As you see, the filter misses some check boxes. Particularly, the filtering specification might be too restrictive, and some check boxes appear to be joined by other characters.

Let's see if we can improve the result by applying some morphology first in order to get rid of the contours that are not part of the check boxes. I'll exploit the fact that the target contours are made of both *horizontal* and *vertical* lines.

Let's create a *"vertical lines"* mask, containing only the vertical lines in the binary image.

```
  //create a vertical structuring element of size 8:
  cv::Mat verticalStructure = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(1, 8) );
  
  //apply the morphology operations to isolate the vertical lines:
  cv::Mat verticalMask = binImage.clone();
  cv::erode( verticalMask, verticalMask, verticalStructure, cv::Point(-1, -1) );
  cv::dilate( verticalMask, verticalMask, verticalStructure, cv::Point(-1, -1) );
```

I'm just applying a `morphological opening` with a vertical line of with `8`, this is the result:

[image]

I'll use the same operations to produce the *"horizontal mask"*. This time the structuring element is as follows:

```
  cv::Mat horizontalStructure = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(8, 1) );
```

The same morphological operations produces this mask:

[image]

We just `OR` the two masks to produce the final binary mask:

[image]

Notice how all the check boxes survived the morphological filters. Very cool, now, compute the contours and filter them accordingly. I've changed the filter parameter, let’s use the `blob area` and see what kind of results we get. I'll be searching for blobs above and below a certain area range.

```
  //contour filter:
  for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ ){

    //get the bounding box for each parent countour found:
    cv::Rect bBox = cv::boundingRect( contours[i] );

    //compute blob area:
    float blobArea = bBox.area();

    //set the area thresholds:
    float minBlobArea = 25;
    float maxBlobArea = 300;

    //set the width/height thresholds:
    float minWidth = 5;
    float minHeight = 5;

    if ( (bBox.height > minHeight) && (bBox.width > minWidth) &&
         (blobArea > minBlobArea ) && (blobArea < maxBlobArea) ) {
          cv::Scalar color = cv::Scalar( 0, 0, 255 );
          cv::drawContours( imageInput, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, cv::Point() );
    }

  }
```

This is the final output you get:

[image]

Comment: Can you do it in python ? Because, I am not advance enough to interpret it into Python